# Remove an unknown number of chars from String java

Tags: java, string, char, trim

I have the following assignment:
Trim the given character from the beginning and end of the given string.
For example, if the given string is "aaahappy birthdayaaaaaaa", and the given character is 'a', returns the string "happy birthday".
I managed to remove the start but I can't figure out a way to remove the ending.
my code:

```
public static String trim(String str, char c) {
    String newStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length () && str.charAt (i) == c; i++) {
            newStr = str.substring (i+1);

    }
    String ans = "";
    for (int j = 0; j<newStr.length () && newStr.charAt (j) == c; j++) {
        ans = newStr.substring (0,j);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

**I cannot use trim or replaceAll, only substring.**
Please give me ideas how to remove the ending without cutting the same character in the middle

Comment: You could always revert haystack and the needle, and do the same again.

Comment: what do you mean?
to reverse twice the string?

Comment: You know how to do the job from the  beginning right? So what will be @ the beginning if you revert the String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forward and backward iterations should be used just to find out the start and end indices for the final string, then a single "subString" call should return the final string.

```
public static String trim(String str, char c) {
    int begIndex = 0;
    while (begIndex<str.length() && str.charAt(begIndex) == c) {
        begIndex++;
    }

    int endIndex = str.length()-1;
    while (endIndex>= 0 && str.charAt(endIndex) == c) {
        endIndex--;
    }
    return str.substring(begIndex, endIndex+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can revert your string by using this:

```
new StringBuilder(yourString).reverse().toString();
```

and then place your method on it again.

Comment: does it need import? if so I am not allowed to use it either

Comment: `StringBuilder` does not require any imports.

Comment: like this?: 'String tmp = new StringBuilder(newStr).reverse().toString();
  String tempReverse = "";
  for (int j = 0; j<tmp.length () && tmp.charAt (j) == c; j++) {
   tempReverse = newStr.substring (j+1);
  }
  String ans = new StringBuilder(tempReverse).reverse().toString();
  return ans;'
because it prints aaaaaaayadhtri

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the string in both directions at the same time:

```
public static String trim(String str, char c) {    
    int start = 0, end = str.length - 1;
    boolean foundStart = false, foundEnd = false;
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < str.length (); i++, j--) {
       if (str.charAt(i) != c && !foundStart) {
         start = i; foundStart = true;
       }

       if (str.charAt(j) != c && !foundEnd) {
         end = j; foundEnd = true;
       }

       if (foundStart && foundEnd) {
          break;
       }
    }

    return str.subString(start, end + 1);
}
```

Coded this is stackOverflow editor, please forgive syntax issues if any :)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thank you! just one thing - I ran this in a tester but I don't understand why your string is out of boundaries?

Comment: @Yuki1112. Fixed it, its `j = str.length - 1` :) Hope this helped you atleast, you can mark as this exists proper compared to above answer, And need not loop twice

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String trim(String str, char c) {
    int beginIndex = -1, endIndex = str.length();

    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
        beginIndex += beginIndex + 1 == i && str.charAt(i) == c ? 1 : 0;
        endIndex -= i != j && endIndex - 1 == j && str.charAt(j) == c ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return str.substring(beginIndex + 1, endIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it more simply

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "aaahappy birthdayaaaaaaa";
    char c = 'a';
    String newStr = str.replaceAll("(^["+c+"]+|["+c+"]+$)", "");
    System.out.println(newStr);

}
```

Comment: Yuki1112 said in the description that replaceAll() is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

public static String getTrimmedString(String s, char c) {

```
    int i = 0;
    int len = s.length();

    while (i<len && s.charAt(i)==c){
        i++;
    }
    while(len>i && s.charAt(len-1)==c){
        len--;
    }
    return s.substring(i, len);
}
```